# Are hyperplanes through the origin the only $n-1$ dimensional subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that sets of the form $\{x:a^T x=0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, $a\ne 0$ (i.e., hyperplanes through the origin) are $n-1$ dimensional subspaces. However, I would like to know if every $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a hyperplane through the origin. That is, for $n-1$ linearly independent points $x_1,\dots, x_{n-1}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, does there exist a nonzero $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$\text{span}\{x_1,\dots, x_{n-1}\}= \{x:a^T x=0\}?$$ I suspect that this is true (?) since when studying vector spaces, we define hyperplanes to be subspaces of one less dimension than the dimension of the ambient space. A proof or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, and $a$ is, for example, the cross product of $x_1, ..., x_{n-1}$.

Comment: The orthogonal complement of your span must be $1$-dimensional (why?).  So taking a representative (nonzero) element of the orthogonal complement will give you your $a$.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. So if we take $a\ne 0$ in the orthogonal complement obviously we get $\subseteq$ by definition. And to get the reverse inclusion $\supseteq$ we use the fact that the orthogonal complement is $1$-dimensional. @Bye_World

Comment: Yep.  Good job.$ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote by $e_i=(0, \dots, 0, 1, 0, \dots, 0)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ the $i$-th standard basis vector.

Pick some $x_n\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x_1, \dots, x_n$ forms a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let

$$ A= \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & \dots & x_n \end{pmatrix}\in Mat(n\times n,\mathbb{R}).$$

We have

$$ Ae_i = x_i.$$

As $x_1, \dots, x_n$ forms a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have that $A$ is invertible. Furthermore, we have

$$ A^{-1}x_i = e_i. $$

Set now

$$ a:=(A^{-1})^T e_n.$$

Then we have

$$ a^T x_i = e_n^T ((A^{-1})^T)^T x_i= e_n^T A^{-1}x_i= e_n^T e_i = \begin{cases} 0; &i\neq n, \\ 1; &i=n, \end{cases}$$

(we just performed a change of coordinates).
Hence,

$$ span\{ x_1, \dots, x_{n-1} \} = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n : a^T x =0\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Find an extra basis vector not in your span, then subtract its projection onto the span. Basically, use the last step of the Gram–Schmidt process. The result is your $x$.